# Draw polygon using JavaScript and the CSS clip-path attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following as my code which gives me my desired effect.

```css
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon( 0% 0%, /*exterior top left*/
  0% 100%, /*exterior bottom left*/
  220px 100%, /*overlapping point exterior 1*/
  220px 50%, /*overlapping point interior 1*/
  220px 310px, /*interior top left*/
  683px 310px, /*interior top right*/
  683px 450px, /*interior bottom right*/
  220px 450px, /*overlapping point interior 2*/
  220px 100%, /*overlapping point exterior 2*/
  100% 100%, /*exterior bottom right*/
  100% 0%);
  /*exterior top right*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Some background</div>
  <div id="overlay">

  </div>
  <div id="closeButton">
    <p>
      Close
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function main() {
      $("#overlay").hide();
      $("#overlay").fadeIn(500);

      $("#closeButton").on("click", function() {
        $("#overlay").toggle();
      });
    }
    $(document).ready(main);
  </script>
</body>
```

I want to know if I could write a function to do the same thing that takes in an array of coordinates so that I don't have to hard code it in every time I want to move the window. It would trigger when the `closeButton` is pressed.

Comment: you mean? the clip path may change after clicking on the close button? and you don't want to write the new values once again?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Yes I want the clip path to change after clicking the close button. 

Not exactly. I want to be able to store a bunch of different polygon coordinates in an array and just use those to change the path of the one clip-path. I want to avoid making a bunch of divs with a bunch of clip paths or making a bunch of classes/ids and changing it in the css

Comment: But do the new values have any logic or any dependency to old ones?

Comment: @possibly but for the purpose of this question no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly compute a polygon string in JavaScript, then set that style on the element. Here's an example function that can take 2 pixel coordinates to create a similar polygon:

```css
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Some background</div>
  <div id="overlay">

  </div>
  <div id="closeButton">
    <p>
      Close
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Copy this function:
    function generatePoly(p1, p2) {
        var a = p1[0] + 'px';
        var b = p1[1] + 'px';
        var c = p2[0] + 'px';
        var d = p2[1] + 'px';
        return 'polygon(' + [
          '0% 0%',
          '0% 100%',
          a + ' 100%',
          a + ' 50%',
          a + ' ' + b,
          c + ' ' + b,
          c + ' ' + d,
          a + ' ' + d,
          a + ' 100%',
          '100% 100%',
          '100% 0%'
        ].join(', ') + ')';
    }

    function main() {

      // Run this when you want to set the polygon:
      $("#overlay").css('clip-path', generatePoly([40, 80], [120, 200]));

      $("#overlay").hide();
      $("#overlay").fadeIn(500);

      $("#closeButton").on("click", function() {
        $("#overlay").toggle();
      });
    }
    $(document).ready(main);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That looks like it's exactly what I wanted but I'm not sure how to implement it?

Comment: @tsubi-rin I added some comments. All you need to do is copy the `generatePoly` function, and call `$("#overlay").css('clip-path', generatePoly([40, 80], [120, 200]));` (with your own coordinates) when you want to use it.

Comment: I saw them and everything works, which is amazing, thank you. 

I didn't notice that the parameters were arrays so it didn't work when I tried it. Everything is great now.